# Looping through Json Array with empty objects

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I am trying to get all the category titles from a JSON array. But not all the objects have a category. Because of this, when I try to append the data, I keep getting undefined and the rest of my data is not appended because of this.

I would like to somehow just give the category a default category if there is none in the Json file. Or even take the title of a tag an make it the category.

I have attempted a few methods, but none seem to work. I have made a snippet below of what I have done so far, along with a download link to the JSON file. I have placed a **ProblemArea** comment to show you what I was attempting.

Any help would be appreciated!

CODE -

```js
$("#search-btn").click(function (e) {
    
            var userText = $.trim($('#searchArea').val());
            $('.full-post-img').css('display', 'none');
            $('.overlay-hugeinc').css('left', '-9999px');
    
            $.getJSON('http://www.capetownetc.com/api/get_search_results/?search=' + userText, {
                    srsearch: userText
                    , action: "query"
                    , list: "search"
                    , format: "json",
                },
                      
                function (data) {

                    $("#searchR").empty().append('<p class="results">RESULTS</p>');
                
                    if(userText.length === 0){
                        $("#searchR").empty().append("<p class='results'>Please enter a keyword</p>");
                         $('#sLoad').css('opacity', '0');
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#swipe").empty();
                        
                        $.each(data.posts, function (i, item) {
//                          $('#sLoad').css('opacity', '0');
                            
                            //EXCERPT
                            var ex = item.excerpt;
                            var maxLength = 100;
                            ex = ex.substr(0, maxLength);
                            
                            //THUMBNAIL
                            var imgThumb1 = item.thumbnail_images.full.url;
                            
                            //****PROBLEM AREA****
                            //CATEGORY
                            var cat = item.categories[0].title;
                            
                            if(cat.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                                console.log('Is valid');
                            }

                            
                            console.log(cat);
                            
                            $("#swipe").append('<div class="p1 full-post-text"><a class="p1 link-click" id="post2" target="_blank"></a><div class="p1 text-post-img"><span class="p1 card-img1" id="p1Img" style="background-image:url(' + imgThumb1 + ');"></span><a class="p1 post-cat">' + cat + '</a> </div><div class="p1 full-text-info"><h2 class="p1 text-heading" id="p1Heading">' + item.title + '</h2><p class="p1 text-post-desc" id="p1Desc">' + ex + '</p><p class="p1 post-source" id="p1Source"> / </p></div></div>');
                            
                    }); 
                    }
                
                });
});
```

[JSON Data File](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=28570357838180962443)

Comment: you can use `yourArray.map()` to recreate your json structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want a quick and dirty check, just have an or-check so you can set a default value if title is undefined.

```
var cat = item.categories[0].title || "default value"
```

And if you really wanna go overboard:

```
var cat = (item && item.categories && item.categories[0] && item.categories[0].title) || "default value"
```

You can clean this with a simple if-statement. Just trying to demonstrate several undefined checks.

Comment: if you're going to go down that second route, you probably also need to check item.categories.length or the next condition will throw an exception

Comment: Ha, you're right - not sure why I thought that. Maybe it was in a different language ...

Comment: You are a champ! Your second solution worked well. I just set the default value to what the user types. I appreciate the help :)